# JSON data sent using JQuery to php not working

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this piece of code to send JSON data to a php file using JQuery but its not working. Its showing no error in console but do not output. If I use var_dump, it outputs array (0){ } in php file. Here is JQuery code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<?php
   function searchResults($q) {
    $host = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" . urlencode( $q ) . "&rpp=100";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    //Raw xml
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
     return json_encode($xml);
     } 
   ?>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var msg_top = <?php echo   
    searchResults('windows');?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $.ajax({
     url: "script.php",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     data: msg_top,
     success: function(){
     alert("success");
     }
    });
   alert("failure");
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my php code:

```
    <?php
     var_dump($_POST);
    ?>
```

Comment: Might be silly, but have you tried grabbing it from $_REQUEST instead of POST?  I've had that problem before.

Comment: are you getting the data from twitter on the server, sending it to the browser, then sending it back to the server to be parsed, then sending the parsed data back to the browser? the reason to use json for this is because it can be used directly on the browser, you dont need to send it to the server for parsing.

Comment: @John Boker, actually I need to store these tweets into mysql. Here 1st I am trying to 1st see if I receive & receive those correctly into php script.

Comment: @Alex C, I tried that but sane. I think if var_dump doesn't print then it means results not reached in php. As I have pointed in my post, I am not sure of php variable really passed to js var. I did this thing 1st time from web search & don't know it its works.

Answer (score 0):

```
data: "msg_top",
```

should be without quotes:

```
data:msg_top,
```

Comment: I removed quotes but same results. Can u see php var assignment to js var, I have done 1st time this stuff by web search, not sure if it works

Answer (score 0):

**On this line:**

```
var msg_top = <?php echo searchResults('windows');?>;
```

**Make the string json:**

```
var msg_top = JSON.parse("<?php echo searchResults('windows');?>");
```

**And also** `data: msg_top`

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell, I did that, it raises two errors in console. First one it highlights this php assignment statement in error window with all results displaying & error ')' missing. & 2nd one is Json not defined at dataType: json, line

Comment: I put quots around json then this error gone, then it says same msg_top, I also put quotes around that it stop showing error for that too. Now error is on php assignment statement

Comment: looks like it is invalid json. Use http://www.jsonlint.com/ to validate the json you are outputting.

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell, yes that function was sending invalid json, I changed the function, its json is validated but same error remains there i.e. php assignment statement in error window with all results displaying & error ')' missing.

Comment: from the code you have in the question I do not see any more problems. Perhaps the type="text/javascript" on your script tags. Make sure you can take the string being output by php and parse it to json.

Comment: if it is failing on JSON.parse then it is still invalid json.

Comment: If I remove the JSON.parse from JSON.parse("<?php echo searchResults('windows');?>");
 , then it shows no error & var_dump outputs array(0){ }.I edited code

Comment: is it necessary that we uase json to send data through jquery ajax? As my only problem is to save tweets into database that my function retrieves, ideally when page loads. Can't xml be POSTed through jquery ajax as that is working fine.

Comment: The reason you use json is because it is the object notation for javascript. XML in javascript would be a string. When you call JSON.parse([string]) it turns the json string into a literal javascript object.

Comment: So what if I remain in php & send that xml object that contains all tweets to php script that runs the query to run a loop & insert all tweets.I mean I use php in spite of js. I chose ajax only so that it inserts all data into database with page refresh. But it I have had spent last 3 days on it to no avail.

Comment: @Josiah, failing on JSON.parse error is removed. I add addslashes() to var msg_top = JSON.parse("<?php echo  addslashes(searchResults('windows'));?>"); & it goes. There is no error but no output except array(0) { }. I think the problem lies in assigning of json from php to js. Is there no other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$msg = json_decode(stripslashes ($_POST['msg_top']), true);
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried but same result. Actually the error is at line "var msg_top = JSON.parse("<?php echo searchResults('windows');?>");". It says 'missing ) after list'

Comment: OK, I add addslashes() & that error is gone but there is no result in php.